# How to build in Visual Studio with include files with paths?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, include, include-path

I am trying to get my project which builds fine on Linux to port to Visual Studio 2008.

At the moment, I am stumped by the behavior of include files where the inclusion specifies a directory path like `#include <botan/zlib.h>`.  There is a zlib.h file in my project, but it seems in visual studio you do not have a directory structure of files, but instead just a collection of files, and thus the path to a file is not relevant.

How can I teach Visual Studio to resolve include files where part of the path to the file is specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path in VS is exactly as relevant as anywhere else. If you want to `#include <botan/zlib.h>`, and the actual path is `C:\folder\botan\zlib.h` - you must add `C:\folder\` to include path.

P. S. Project tree in VS is indeed unrelated to the physical project structure in filesystem. If you want to make your project look nice - use filters (right click on project or filter -> Add -> New Filter).

Comment: You would only add `C:\folder` to the path.  The use of `botan` in `#include <botan/zlib.h>` would initiate looking for a subdirectory of `boton` in each search path component.

Comment: I added to project -> properties dialog in the configuration properties -> C/C++ -> General for the Additional Include Directories entry, but still the zlib.h is not found, no such file or directory, C1083.

Comment: @WilliamKF: try configuration properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories. I always use that option for specifying include paths.

Comment: There is no 'VC++ Directories' under configuration properties in my Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: @WilliamKF: Ouch, sorry, that was added in VS2010. In VS2008 it's Tools->Options-> __Something__ . Sorry, I can't remember what is this __Something__, exactly, so you'll have to dig a bit.

Comment: I located that, but still get same error after adding directory where Botan directory exists to INCLUDE path.